# How to add unique index and delete duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add a unique index in my DB, but some data has already been duplicated.
I am trying out this using a test table before applying to the actual one.
It seems that if there are duplicated rows then we wouldn't be able to add the unique constraint.
I want to add the unique constraint and do not care which row gets deleted.

When I run the following

```
ALTER TABLE test_user ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint UNIQUE (personid);
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "test_constraint"
DETAIL:  Key (personid)=(1) is duplicated.
SQL state: 23505
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I am using Postgres as the DB

Comment: Look at examples here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 4):

Create a copy of the table eliminating duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE test_user_new (LIKE test_user);

INSERT INTO test_user_new
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM test_user;

ALTER TABLE test_user_new PRIMARY KEY (personid);
```

Then replace the original table:

```
DROP TABLE test_user;

ALTER TABLE test_user_new RENAME TO test_user;
```